# Keeping radio/checkbox values on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, textbox, radio-button

There's is something I don't get with ASP objects. I have a button in a update panel. On the same page, I have a checkbox, a radiobutton and a textbox (outside the update panel). When I click on my button, I access all those three objects. The textbox is able to keep the his text value. But the radio/checkbox always return false when I check there checked state.

Of course, my form is more complicated than what I just said. It involves Javascript and usercontrols. I managed to use the Request.Form to get the value of my checkbox/radio, but I don't find this solution to be neat enought.

Someone can help me to find why radio/check wont return there real checked state ? Thank you in advance!

Edit :
I've tried to following in a simple aspx page and it seems to works :

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox" />

    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="radio1" GroupName="radio" CssClass="testRadio" />
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="radio2" GroupName="radio" CssClass="testRadio" />

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text" />


    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="test_but" OnClick="test_click" />

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then I can access all the properties into test_click(). So there is something in my real forms that breaks everything else. I've tried to add a little javascript into my test page, and it seems to works too.

Comment: Have you enabled autopostback on the checkbox/radiobutton? if not the postback may only be sending the textbox value, and with autopostback on the checkbox and radiobutton it would have to keep such value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue with these controls. Use the SaveViewState and LoadViewState methods to store and retrieve these values.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153240/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110205-1.aspx

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);

    if (ViewState["Checked"] != null)
        checked = (bool)ViewState["Checked"];
}

protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    ViewState["Checked"] = checked;

    return base.SaveViewState();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? This would be a real big issue no?

Comment: Updating answer - give a try. Could never understand why this was not better documented...

Comment: Try it without the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this solution. It could be a really clean one! I've tried it with and without the upadate panel. The only problem, is that SaveViewState is not invoke before the postback of the button starts. I guess I need to invoke it by myself, but where? In the page_load if it's a postback ? I think it's already too late.

Comment: Not sure about how to make this work with the UpdatePanel, but for a regular form, the above approach has worked for me :) Just use a regular handler for the button.

Comment: For now, I ended up with a function in my Page_Load which take every checkboxes and radiobuttons, check in Request.Form if they are checked, and set checked=true if so. This is more neat than directly playing with Request.Form in the rest of my code, but I still would like to understand why this really simple feature wont works!

Comment: @IrishChieftain: And how to handle if I have the checkox inside of an repeater?