# How to keep the values of checkboxes after postback in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, datalist

I have a `checkbox` in `datalist`, after the button is clicked(`postback`) the value of checkbox is cleared. For example, if the `checkbox` in `datalist` is checked, when the button is clicked the checkbox appears unchecked when getting it's value

Comment: `UpdatePanel`s, `ViewState`'s could help.Here check this Irish guy's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8271782/647884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Put your databinding code in Page load inside

```
If (!IsPostBack)
{
     //Bind  Data 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you are binding your DataList incorrectly.

You need to check if Not Page.IsPostBack, and bind in there.  Otherwise, you are binding every postback and resetting all values.