# c# postback dropdownlist always choose first value

Tags: c#

I want to insert the selected item of drop down list into database but my drop down list keep returns  the first option . auto post back is false . 
codes here :

dropTask() =  drop down list where I populate it from database.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dropTask();
        }


    }

    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {


        String pathdirectory = (dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Text+"/");
        String filepathImage = (pathdirectory + e.FileName);

        EnsureDirectoriesExist(pathdirectory);

        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filepathImage));


        Session["filepathImage"] = filepathImage;

    }
```

i had checked the value return from drop down list using label :

```
   protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["filepathImage"] != null)
        {
            string filepathImage = Session["filepathImage"] as string;


            Label1.Text = filepathImage;

        }

    }
```

the label text show the first option of the drop down list value instead of the choice I have chosen . Please enlighten me on this .

ASPX:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <h2>Upload your Story!</h2>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan = "2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <b>Select Activity:</b>
    </td>
    <td> 

        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropListActivity" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="dropListActivity_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>


    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan = "2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <b>Story Title:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStoryTitle" runat="server" 
            ontextchanged="txtTitle_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="style1">
          <b>Upload your files here:</b><br />
          Multiple Images and 1 Audio file only.
    </td>
    <td class="style1">
        <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" 
             /> 
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan = "2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </td>

    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDone" runat="server" Text="Done" onclick="btnDone_Click" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: is the dropdownlist control in the ajax panel?

Comment: not sure what u mean ... if u mean i drag the drop down list from the ajax tab then no... sorry i am a newbie.

Comment: :did you use the ajax controls to upload?if you did,the dropdownlist control and the file upload control must in the same ajax update panel.

Comment: yes i use ajax to upload . sorry but what u mean by update panel?

Comment: any help on this ~ please :)

Comment: Show us your page markup, and we will try to help!

Comment: Sorry ! didn't see your previous comment ! i updated wth aspx !

Comment: What happens on dropListActivity_SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: i never used the ajax controls to do the ajax thing,but i knew when you use ajax control,the update panel is must.dont you use the ajax panel?i think you should google it.

Comment: @user2376998 post your entire aspx and aspx.vb code..maybe that will enable us to help you more

Answer (score 2):

`DropListActivity.SelectedItem.ToString` should do the trick. There are a few other things you should keep in mind:

1. Make sure you are not populating the dropdownlist on a postback.
2. Selected value will only be available at the sever if the portion of
   the page containing the dropdownlist control is posted back.i.e if
   you are using an update panel your dropdownlist should be present
   within that panel or if you are posting back the entire page then there wont be any problem at all provided you meet the first criteria.
3. Your event handler `dropListActivity_SelectedIndexChanged` will
   always be fired when a page is posted back and the seleceted index
   has changed. The event handler `dropListActivity_SelectedIndexChanged` will be called after the `page_load subroutine` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need something like:

```
private void SaveSelected()
{
    ViewState["SelectedItem"] = dropListActivity.SelectedItem;
}
```

which you use on `dropListActivity_SelectedIndexChanged` and

```
private void LoadSelected()
{
   if (ViewState["SelectedItem"] != null)
        dropListActivity.SelectedItem = (ListItem)ViewState["SelectedItem"];
}
```

which you call after `dropTask();`

Please, refer to [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271654/keeping-radio-checkbox-values-on-postback)

Comment: hi there , thanks for the help man appreciate it , but there is an error with ListIem -> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'string'

Comment: It's not the exact code, I hoped you'll get the idea. You can use SelectedItem.ToString() for example, or store SelectedItemIndex, if you wish.

Comment: sorry i am a slow learner , logic/idea doesn't flow correctly in me ... please enlighten me more on this :)

Answer (score 0):

in dropListActivity_SelectedIndexChanged event do like

```
if(dropListActivity.Items.Count > 0)
{
    ViewState["DropDownSelectedValue"] = dropListActivity.Item.SelectedValue;
}
```

and on Load or databind of drop down list event write

```
if(ViewState["DropDownSelectedValue"] != null && dropListActivity.Items.Count > 0)
{
    dropListActivity.SelectedValue = ViewState["DropDownSelectedValue"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: this somehow remove all my data in the drop down list which i had populated it from db

Comment: is the drop down binding in postback or no. it should not remove the elements from the drop down list.

Comment: i posted the codes , its in (!Page.IsPostBack) , even if i put it outside of postback and in the page load , the problem's still there